# Pass paste content to a NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, uipasteboard

I'm to make a button that pastes the "paste" content into a UITextView, when the user clicks a UIButton.

How could I do that?
And, can I send the value to a NSString before? Then verify if it's a valid link?

Comment: See the docs for `UIPasteBoard`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'll read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
textView.text = pasteBoard.string;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much. I'll read the UIPastBoard documentation as @maddy recommended too.